# Trying to create DRY strikethrough text for multiple spans while hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to create a simple webpage where you can hover over sets of words. When you hover, I would like all other words you are not hovering over to become struck out.

The HTML is:

> ```
>       <div class="row col-xs-12" id="jobs">
>             <h2><span class="selector">Writer and Editor</span>, <span class="selector">Social Media Slayer</span>, <span class="selector">Amateur Developer</span>.</h2>
>         </div>
> ```
>
> Right now I have a simple jQuery function that, when I hover over each element, changes the spans font color like so:

```
$('.selector').hover(function(){
    $(this).css('color', '#fddbd1');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'white');
});
```

What I would like to do is also have a script that, on hover, strikes out the text in every span that is not being hovered over. I would also like it so that when you click on each span, the strike outs in the other spans remain until you click elsewhere.

I know how to do this with lots of repetitive code, but I was hoping to make it nice and DRY.

Answer (score 0):

To strikethrough all spans class selector that are not hovered over, and retain strikethrough on clicking on element, removing when clicking on another element.

```
$('.selector').hover(function(){
    // Cleanup / Reset to default position
    $('.selector').removeClass('clicked');
    $('.selector').css('text-decoration', 'none');

    $('.selector').not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    });
}, function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked'))
    {
        $('.selector').not(this).each(function() {
            $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
        });
    }    
});
$('.selector').click(function(evt) {
    $('.selector').not(this).each(function() {
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
   });
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
$('body').click(function(evt) {
    if(!$(evt.target).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $('.selector').css('text-decoration', 'none');
   }

});
```